# Sizeof of std::function<void(int&)> type

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, c++11

What kind of magic does the `std::function<void(int&)>` from C++11 that its `sizeof = 32`? If I'd store the function reference as a pointer, it'd cost only `8 bytes` (on a 64 bit machine).

Comment: Probably small-functor optimization.

Comment: Consider the size of member function pointers, first of all.

Comment: @GManNickG Yes, that's what I'm asking for, i.e. the internals. These STL files are quite unreadable so I wonder if somebody knows it precisely.

Comment: I don't think it can be reasonably claimed that `std::function` is or ever was part of the STL.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit O wow. You're getting mild these days :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For `std::function<Signature>` it is a trade-off between object size and allocation which is interesting: For small function objects it is desirable to avoid an allocation. On the other hand, doing so increases the object size. For the small function optimization to be useful and not introduce overheads when actually calling the object, the object size needs to be at least two pointers plus some memory to store simple function objects. It seems that a size of 32 bytes is exactly this (on a system where `sizeof(T*)` is 8).

That is, internally a `std::function<Signature>` object stores an inheritance hierarchy: The base class provides the interface to be called, delegating to a templatized derived which implements the call interface (plus, probably, some `clone()` functionality). In an implementation optimized for size the function object would just keep a pointer to the base, but to avoid allocation it would set aside some internal storage to allocate the entire object in and point to this object (the internal pointer avoids a condition when actually calling the function object). The memory needed for the object is a virtual function pointer plus any data for the actual function object the `std::function<Signature>` object is initialized with. To accommodate member functions with their object it seems that two more words is reasonably small.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: One pointer to point to the base and a virtual function pointer. Plus, the data for the actual function object.

Comment: I don't understand where the virtual function pointer comes from, but I'll leave it.

Comment: Internally, the `std::function<R(A...)>` uses a base class with a virtual function, e.g., `struct FB { virtual R call(A...) = 0; virtual ~FB() {} };` and when assigning a function object to the object it creates a corresponding derived class.

Comment: Looking at the actual implementation, it seems libstdc++ trades a run-time dispatch for storing a pointer in case the object is embedded into the actual function. libcxx uses a more vanilla implementation described above.

Answer (score 9):

`std::function` is indeed magic, as it can be constructed from *any* callable object! It will happily store any amount of state for you, even if on the surface you retain a measly `void(int&)` signature.

There's certainly a price attached to this magic, which typically uses some sort of type erasure (i.e. a dynamic allocation and virtual dispatch) internally. The details vary, but the resulting objects are certainly "heavy" — which is why they should be avoided in favour of `auto` and templates whenever feasible!

Comment: How can one store a state in the `std::function` object? I thought that this `std::function` was only a kind of a "safe C++ function pointer", but it is more, right?

Comment: @Martin: It's a lot more -- for starters, `std::function` is a *template*, not a class. And it is indeed full of magic. Lots of templated constructors and SFINAE etc. Look at the source if you want to get an idea.

Comment: @Martin If I have `struct big { void operator()() {}; char dummy[N]; };` then I can store an arbitrary amount of bytes in an `std::function<void()> f = big {};`.

Comment: @LucDanton Oh, I see. It's that flexible. Thank you.