# Is it possible to accept the output of `std::bind` directly as a value, without conversion to std::function?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, stdbind

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25403584/391161) states that `std::bind` returns an object by value, and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614574/where-in-the-source-does-gccs-stdbind-copy-arguments-into-a-data-structure#comment60828444_36614574) implies that assigning to `std::function` will cause a heap allocation to store the value returned by `std::bind`.

Is there a way to avoid this heap allocation and pass the return value of `std::bind` to another function directly by value?

If so, what would the method signature replace `std::function` with?

---

To be more explicit, I have a function like the following.

```
void runThisFunction(std::function<void()> func);
```

Suppose there is a function `foo` with the following signature.

```
void foo(int a, int b);
```

Now, I would invoke `runThisFunction` as follows.

```
runThisFunction(std::bind(foo, 1, 2));
```

In this invocation, the output of `std::bind` is converted into an `std::function`, and dynamic memory allocation occurs as part of this process.

Is it possible to replace `std::function` with some other declaration that would would receive the output of `std::bind` directly by value, thereby avoiding the dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: does `template <class T> void runThisFunction(T func)` count?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, That feels like it might work. It does suffer from the usual problem with templates (generating one copy of code for every type), but I suppose it can't be helped.

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted. It simply did not occur to me to use a template to solve this problem, although it seems obvious in hindsight.

Comment: If you don't like templates, and the callers don't vary enough to actually need them, you could try `void runThisFunction(decltype(std::bind(foo, 1, 2))& func);` - I suspect you'd be able to call it with any `std::bind()` invocation where the argument's static types match `foo`, `1` and `2`, but you'd have to dig into the Standard to see if that's guaranteed.

Comment: How often are you running this function?  On the equivalent of a per-pixel per-frame basis or similar?  (like many millions of times/second?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to replace `std::function` with some other declaration that would would receive the output of `std::bind` directly by value, thereby avoiding the dynamic memory allocation?

Yes it is; but the type returned by `std::bind` is unspecified, so you will need to use a template to capture the type;

```
template <typename F>
void runThisFunction(F func);
```

On the memory allocation...

> In this invocation, the output of `std::bind` is converted into an `std::function`, and dynamic memory allocation occurs as part of this process.

Dynamic memory may be used (but not [always](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13503614/3747990)), it depends on the size of the functor being bound into the `std::function` and the quality of implementation.

Further, the C++ spec has this [§20.12.12.2.1/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.func.con#11);

> [Note: Implementations are encouraged to avoid the use of dynamically allocated memory for small callable objects, for example, where `f` is an object holding only a pointer or reference to an object and a member function pointer.
>   — end note ]

I would not be too concerned about the memory allocation even if there is one. Unless the code is performance critical and you have measured it as such, the indirection required should not be a problem.

Bear in mind that for your case, the `foo` being bound in the `bind` is a pointer and it is likely that there would be no dynamic memory allocation anyway.

---

> I started looking at this because I measured cache misses on the conversion due to unexpected slowness detected through instrumentation

So you have some measured concerns about the performance... there are alternatives to using `std::bind` paired with `std::function`. `std::bind` is useful general purpose binder, but that doesn't mean it will also be performant enough - make your own. A custom functor could be more performant. A lambda based implementation would also be good to look at. Don't forget either that the function `foo` can be used with `std::function` as well and then you forgo the functor/binder completely (caveat, the signatures need to match).

---

*A side note on how "small" the object needs to be* before the "small object" optimisations mentioned in the quote above kick in seems to vary between the library implementations quiet a bit.

Here on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e05f6c18aa667d3d) (libstdc++), the size of the argument for `std::function` needs to be 16 bytes or less, on [MSVC](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net), the limit is 32 bytes (both of these look to be 32-bit platforms). With a clang++ (libc++) 64-bit compile, this limit is 24 bytes... It really is up to the implementation how much space they will allow for before `new` allocations need to be made.

I'm not sure how critical the performance is, but calculating this limit for your targets could also be done and then optimisations applied such that the arguments for the `std::function` are kept below these limits; e.g. using a pointer or reference (also `std::ref`) to a `struct` for arguments (but care must be taken that these are not left dangling).

Comment: I started looking at this because I measured cache misses on the conversion due to unexpected slowness detected through instrumentation. I think this answer will work, but I'll accept after I test it tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: This answer works, but making the receiving function templated turns out to be more painful than I expected, because it means pulling a lot of state into a header file that I had originally hidden neatly into the cc file.

Comment: It is one of the draw backs, unspecified types tend to do that. I would say you could investigate a redesign, but that is whole other problem and could also be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is important but you still want a concrete interface, consider binding to a lambda rather than a binder object (via std::bind).

I ran this test on gcc 5.3 (libstdc++, -O2)

```
#include <functional>

void foo(int, int);

void runThisFunction(std::function<void()> func);

void test()
{
  runThisFunction(std::bind(&foo, 1, 2));
}

void test1()
{
  runThisFunction([]{ foo(1, 2); });
}
```

`test()` results in a call to `new`. However, the small function optimisation in `std::function` is able to detect that the lambda in `test1()` is small enough and a call to `new` is not emitted into the code:

(note: exception handling code removed for clarity):

```
std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<test1()::{lambda()#1}>::_M_manager(std::_Any_data&, std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<test1()::{lambda()#1}> const&, std::_Manager_operation):
        testl   %edx, %edx
        je      .L3
        cmpl    $1, %edx
        jne     .L2
        movq    %rsi, (%rdi)
.L2:
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        ret
.L3:
        movq    typeinfo for test1()::{lambda()#1}, (%rdi)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        ret
std::_Function_handler<void (), test1()::{lambda()#1}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&):
        movl    $2, %esi
        movl    $1, %edi
        jmp     foo(int, int)
test1():
        subq    $40, %rsp
        movq    %rsp, %rdi
        movq    std::_Function_handler<void (), test1()::{lambda()#1}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&), 24(%rsp)
        movq    std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<test1()::{lambda()#1}>::_M_manager(std::_Any_data&, std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<test1()::{lambda()#1}> const&, std::_Manager_operation), 16(%rsp)
        call    runThisFunction(std::function<void ()>)
        movq    16(%rsp), %rax
        testq   %rax, %rax
        je      .L7
        movl    $3, %edx
        movq    %rsp, %rsi
        movq    %rsp, %rdi
        call    *%rax
.L7:
        addq    $40, %rsp
        ret
typeinfo for test1()::{lambda()#1}:
typeinfo name for test1()::{lambda()#1}:
```

Comment: The guaranty of no allocation in `std::function` is for pointer and `reference_wrapper` (and encouraged for small object). Your lambda is not capturing anything here (so may be converted in function pointer). Things might be different with capture.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, the small function optimisation will have a limit on its aggressiveness depending on the standard library implementation. However, I can't speculate on future scenarios the OP might have - this is the one he presented.

Comment: It's interesting to know that lambda performs better under some circumstances, considering the fact that I switched to `std::bind` specifically because [lambda didn't work under gcc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474417/is-it-possible-to-capture-a-variable-number-of-parameters-in-a-lambda).

Comment: @merlin2011 interesting, but you saw the workaround? to pass the callable by value? I would have thought that copy-elision will mean that it's no slower.

Comment: @RichardHodges, I used `std::bind` specifically because the lambda with varargs would not compile.

Answer (score 1):

By using reference wrapper, you should avoid the heap allocation:

```
auto f = std::bind(foo, 1, 2);
runThisFunction(std::ref(f));
```

This because `reference_wrapper` is a small object and `std::function` is encouraged to avoid allocation for small (see [func.wrap.func.con]):

> Note: Implementations are encouraged to avoid the use of dynamically
>   allocated memory for small callable objects, for example, where f’s
>   target is an object holding only a
>   pointer or reference to an object and a member function pointer.

It will only work if `runThisFunction()` is not storing the value of the `std::function` for calling after the lifetime of `f`.

Comment: Neat alternative with the `std::ref`.  I don't think a simple invocation of the function is all the `runThisFunction` does, thus this needs to come with the caveat that the bind `f` needs to remain alive for at least as long as the `runThisFunction` requires the `std::function` (and whatever else `runThisFunction` feeds the function to, e.g. a list of some sort).

Answer (score -1):

very simple (at least for gcc):

```
int someFunc(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
//....
int b = (std::bind(someFunc,3,4))(); // returns 7
```